# Unable to setup Memcached with TLS

Tags: ssl, memcached, tls1.2

Can someone help me with how can I setup memcached with TLS. I tried following Memcache wiki to no avail.
Compiled the source with --enable-tls and when trying to start the memcache service getting the following error:

> memcached --enable-ssl -o ssl_ca_cert=/etc/ssl/localcerts/memcache.pem -u memcache -v
> 140062054467392:error:20074002:BIO routines:file_ctrl:system lib:crypto/bio/bss_file.c:293:
> 140062054467392:error:140DC002:SSL routines:use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl/ssl_rsa.c:615:
> Error loading the certificate chain: (null) : error:0200100E:system library:fopen:Bad address

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably starting incorrectly your memcached instance. This is correct command line:

```sh
/memcached --protocol=auto -p 11211 --enable-ssl -o ssl_chain_cert=/etc/ssl/localcerts/memcache.pem,ssl_key=/etc/ssl/localcerts/memcache.key -v
```